# efficient numerical algorithm for matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

It appears that in numerical analysis the question of computing the determinant $\det A$ of a real or a complex $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is not well-studied, and a usual recommendation is to use matrix factorisation, e.g $PLU$-factorisation $A=LU$, with $L$ and $U$ being lower and upper diagonal matrices, and $P$ a permutation matrix respectively. It's known to need $2n^3/3$ *flops* (floating point operations), cf.
*Golub, Gene; Van Loan, Charles F.*, [**Matrix computations.**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/3.2#ii.p2), Baltimore, MD: The Johns Hopkins Univ. Press. xxvii, 694 p. (1996). [ZBL0865.65009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0865.65009).

There are various corner cases there, in particular exponential in $n$ intermediate coefficients growth can occur in the worst case (dismissed as "highly unlikely in practice" in [loc.cit.])

Naively, such a computation is indeed an overkill, and there ought to be more robust, iterative, methods available. E.g. something based on a well-known (usually written for $\det(I-A)$ rather than $A$) formula

$$
\det A=\exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\text{Tr}(I-A)^n}n\right)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{\text{Tr}(I-A)^n}n\right).
$$

While this looks slow to compute, for each term in the product needs $O(n^3)$ flops, perhaps there is a numerical analysis magic to make it fast.

---

Note that if $A$ is positive definite then one can rescale $A$ so that all its eigenvalues are small in absolute value, to ensure convergence of this series (and then rescale back)

Comment: It is folklore that determinant is as hard as inverse is as hard as multiplication (though there are some subtleties in this identification). If a matrix is sparse or structured you can do better than $O(n^2)$---let alone $O(n^\omega)$ or $O(n^3)$---using "black box" methods that exploit the speed of an oracle $x \mapsto Ax$. But in practice PLU is indeed preferred for small dense matrices (provided that Coppersmith-Winograd-Strassen is more trouble than it's worth). I once had a guy working for me implement this because we had to count every flop.

Comment: You mean that your matrix is close to $I$? Otherwise your series with traces can easily just diverge. Anyway, there seems to be no fast *general* method available but if you tell *exactly* what matrices you are interested in, there *may* be a possibility to invent some ad hoc technique for that class.

Comment: for the purposes of computing $\det A$ one can assume $|\lambda|<1$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$. (rescaling the result is easy, as well as scaling $A$ so that its Gershgorin discs are small enough).

Comment: Erm... So if the initial eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$, what $\lambda$ are you offering to choose to get the eigenvalues of $I-\lambda A$ less than $1$ in absolute value? (it is $I-\lambda A$, not $\lambda A$, which is raised to high powers in your formula).

Comment: oops, sorry, OK, I worked with psd matrices too much... At least, the trick works for psd matrices.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman, I've only skimmed it so far, but https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.04662 may allow the removal of your comment about subtleties (or it may just make them even more subtle than was previously the case).

Comment: Thanks - that work sweeps under the carpet numeric difficulties (complexity measured in terms of field operations), but it has an interesting Previous work section.